# Can't access jupyter notebook inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, dockerfile

I know there are a lot of questions of people who are struggling with this but please read the entire post.
So I just want to create a dockerfile that exposes port 8888 to access a jupyter notebook later on.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ARG USERNAME=remote
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

COPY environment.yml* noop.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    && apt-get -y install git openssh-client less iproute2 procps iproute2 lsb-release \
    && if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then /opt/conda/bin/conda env update -n base -f /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; else echo "did not find environment.yml"; fi \
    && rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp \
    && groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog

EXPOSE 8888
```

I run the following commands to get the container up and running:

```
docker build -t intel . (create the image)
docker run -t -d --publish=8888:8888 --name ig intel (start a container based on the image)
```

Everything up to this moment runs without any problems, but now comes the thing I don't understand:
This runs just fine.
[image: jupyter notebook --allow-root --no-browser --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888]

But when I try to go to

```
localhost:8888?/token=(the token jupyter provides)
or
ipofthecontainer:8888?/token=(the token jupyter provides)
```

It does nothing(connection timed out) and I have no clue why.

I check the ip of the container with:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name
```

and I verify that the EXPOSE worked with:

[image: docker ps]

platform: windows
python-version: 3.7.7
conda environment: yes

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: What's the `CMD` your container runs?

Comment: @DavidMaze If you mean CMD in the dockerfile: nothing is specified. If you mean which terminal is used in the dockercontainer itself: its a bash terminal. Is this an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, but no...if the only thing the container runs is an interactive shell, then nothing will be listening on the network port.  Usually you'd set `CMD` to run the program packaged in the container, and you can `docker run --rm -it intelligait3d /bin/sh` if you need a one-off shell to debug things.

Comment: Turned out to just be a problem with the ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXPOSE` is only for documentation; it has no effect.

You need to add `--publish=8888:8888` to your `docker run` so that the container's port is mapped to a host port.

```
docker run --tty --detach --publish=8888:8888 --name=ig intelligait3d
```

> **NB** The `publish` flag does not require the `host-port:container-port` to match

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that EXPOSE only served as documentation. However, I tried to run the container with the command you provided. But It doesn't seem to change anything. Do you maybe have some other suggestions on what I could try?
When I use docker ps it now shows '0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp' instead of just '8888/tcp' tho

Answer (score 3):

First modify your docker file in order to start jupyter notebook, add this line at the end of the Dockerfile:

`CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]`

Then build again the image and when you start the container use `-p` option:  `--publish , -p       Publish a container’s port(s) to the host`

`docker run -t -d -p 8888:8888 --name ig intelligait3d` where the mapping is `-p <HOST port>:<CONTAINER port>`

Here you can find the reference for `docker run` command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Correct, I just tried to publish to ports  but it still get a connection timed out when trying to connect to the container.

Comment: You just need the command that starts up the notebook at the end of the Dockerfile.

Comment: I just added the CMD you provided to the end of the dockerfile, build the image again, and ran it but the problem still persists.

Comment: It ended up being just a problem with the ports.
I changed the CMD that you suggested to make use of the port 8889 instead of 8888. I also changed the command to run the container to ```docker run -t -d --publish=8889:8889 intelligait3d```

Comment: Setting `--ip=0.0.0.0` was what made Jupyter lab accessible from outside for me.